# How to filter a list without converting to string or loop it

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

I've got an object of type list and second object of type string.
I would like to filter for all values in the list-object which do not match the value of the string-object.

I have created a loop which splits the list into string and with regex found all those not matching and added these results to a new list.
This example uses hostnames "ma-tsp-a01", "ma-tsp-a02" an "ma-tsp-a03".
Currently I do further work on this new list to create a clean list of hostnames.

```py
import re
local_hostname = 'ma-tsp-a01'
profile_files = ['/path/to/file/TSP_D01_ma-tsp-a01\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_D02_ma-tsp-a02\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_ASCS00_ma-tsp-a01\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS03_ma-tsp-a03\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS01_ma-tsp-a01\n']
result_list = [local_hostname]
for list_obj in profile_files:
    if re.search(".*\w{3}\_\w{1,7}\d{2}\_(?!"+local_hostname+").*", list_obj):
        result_list.append(list_obj.split("/")[-1].splitlines()[0].\
split("_")[-1])
print(result_list)
```

At the end I get the following output
`['ma-tsp-a01', 'ma-tsp-a02', 'ma-tsp-a03']`. This looks exactly what I am searching for. But is there a way to make this in a more pythonic way without the "for" loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `filter` object:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: re.search(".*\w{3}\_\w{1,7}\d{2}\_(?!"+local_hostname+").*", x), profile_files)
```

Or use a generator comprehension:

```
filtered = (x for x in profile_files if re.search(".*\w{3}\_\w{1,7}\d{2}\_(?!"+local_hostname+").*", x))
```

Both behave the same

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand how to use the filtered result any further.
Using your first proposed solution I get `<filter object at 0x7f7e49eec550>` this does not show me any readable values.

Using the second proposal I get a `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd2bdca8620>`

Can you help me how to use these results any further to have a list that looks the same as in my question?

Comment: @nsolthe, your just need to consume them with list to have the values, for example list(filtered)